# Get Facebook profile photos 

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

I am trying to get the photos in a user profile. I tried to use `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos`, but it returns tagged photos only. Can I get all the photos in all albums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) endpoint, you want the [albums endpoint](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api).

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums

From the API page:

- Photo Tags: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
- Photo Albums: https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums

From that you can then call `https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos`.

Comment: that only return the album not the photos inside it

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks, but how did that "rest request" know that it was me, /me/ or my id is not included in the url. let's ask the question in different way, how to get my friends photos??

Comment: From your access token, it uses facebook privileges to see if you are allowed.